Statefulset for apps deployed by spring cloud data flow in Kubernetes
I know this question was asked last year and that isnt supported then, but is it still the same?
in SCDF(Spring Cloud Data Flow), how can i deploy application(stream or task) as statefulset? not deployment
The use case for us is due to a few apps in our streams that use topic enrichment or windowed aggregation which writes to local disk (/tmp/kafka-streams default location) and we want to minimize our deployment or crash restart of app to minimum, by not having to re-read the whole topic back into disk.
While looking at the deployer spi for a different reason, stumbled upon this line, which does decide on Statefulset vs Deployment, but is that something for the future? As the property it seems to depend on, was given both at app and deployer properties, but do not see a stateful set created
spring.cloud.deployer.indexed=true
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-kubernetes/blob/0b84199d17788e1d05e5f3bab5df91ff0863b1e3/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/deployer/spi/kubernetes/KubernetesAppDeployer.java#L126
Please do advise on if this limitation continues to exist, we are currently on 2.9.6, but are planning an upgrade and it its version dependent, the upgrade effort can be prioritized by us to get this working.

If you define time | log as a stream named timelogger and then add the property deployer.time.indexed=true you will see that there is no Deployment for timelogger-time but a StatefulSet.

Thanks for response. Am able to get the Statefulset working with specific storage class on efs. I do have some followup problems. Our storage class uses dynamic provisioning which contains PVC name in it. This would mean every deploy will get a new folder which means already downloaded disk cache is not used and kafka streams will download all data again. Am trying to work with my cloud admin team to see if we can play around with the path in efs, but are there other ways i can control the name to be static w.o -vxx

I would suggest logging an issue describing your use-case and problems so that we can find a good solution. At the moment Spring Cloud Deployer derives the names from the stream and app. It seems there is more required than just fixing a volumeName.

I believe is may be better to look at supporting a dataSource in the PVC which allows you to use an existing PersistentVolumeClaim or VolumeSnapshot as the dataSource.

Adding a plain volume using deployer.volumes property as described here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer/blob/c827c35bd5e0974d4d659e760b57382aaed5ebe5/spring-cloud-deployer-kubernetes/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/deployer/spi/kubernetes/DeploymentPropertiesResolver.java#L120

Please add comments to https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer/issues/446
